# Dictionary with lists as values - find longest list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

I have a dictionary where the values are lists. I need to find which key has the longest list as value, after removing the duplicates. If i just find the longest list this won't work as there may be a lot of duplicates. I have tried several things, but nothing is remotely close to being correct.

Comment: It's best to share your efforts with the question too.

Comment: I will do this next time. My efforts were not correct at all, that's why I thought there was no point in writing them here.

Comment: I don't understand why you are worried about duplicates.  If they are the same, they have the same length and that won't affect the max.  Dictionaries aren't ordered, so it might be tricky to find the "first" key that has the longest list.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not show any attempt at solving the issue.

Comment: Again, I'm sorry I didn't post my attempts, I will next time, however bad they might be :)

Comment: @njzk2 I strongly disagree, as "showing your work" is not a requirement for being on-topic on stack overflow. There was a lengthy mod post about this not horribly long ago, though my google-fu is lacking at the moment.... OP clearly understands the problem, explained it concisely, and mentioned that he'd tried several things.

Comment: @njzk2 Ah, found it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort

Comment: @adsmith: i disagree as well, for various reasons, that have already been debated. For example, I'd rather tell them why their attempts failed, or how to fix the code already written, or give a nudge in the correct direction. Also, attempts, as well as input and output, give a good notion of what is being attempted.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
d = # your dictionary of lists

max_key = max(d, key= lambda x: len(set(d[x])))
# here's the short version. I'll explain....

max( # the function that grabs the biggest value
    d, # this is the dictionary, it iterates through and grabs each key...
    key = # this overrides the default behavior of max
        lambda x: # defines a lambda to handle new behavior for max
            len( # the length of...
                set( # the set containing (sets have no duplicates)
                    d[x] # the list defined by key `x`
                   )
               )
   )
```

Since the code for `max` iterates through the dictionaries' keys (that's what a dictionary iterates through, by the by. `for x in dict: print x` will print each key in `dict`) it will return the key that it finds to have the highest result when it applies the function we built (that's what the `lambda` does) for `key=`. You could literally do ANYTHING here, that's the beauty of it. However, if you wanted the key AND the value, you might be able to do something like this....

```
d = # your dictionary

max_key, max_value = max(d.items(), key = lambda k,v: len(set(v)))
# THIS DOESN'T WORK, SEE MY NOTE AT BOTTOM
```

This differs because instead of passing `d`, which is a dictionary, we pass `d.items()`, which is a list of tuples built from `d`'s keys and values. As example:

```
d = {"foo":"bar", "spam":['green','eggs','and','ham']}
print(d.items())
# [ ("foo", "bar"),
#   ("spam", ["green","eggs","and","ham"])]
```

We're not looking at a dictionary anymore, but all the data is still there! It makes it easier to deal with using the unpack statement I used: `max_key, max_value =`. This works the same way as if you did `WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1024, 768`. `max` still works as usual, it iterates through the new list we built with `d.items()` and passes those values to its `key` function (the `lambda k,v: len(set(v))`). You'll also notice we don't have to do `len(set(d[k]))` but instead are operating directly on `v`, that's because `d.items()` has already created the `d[k]` value, and using `lambda k,v` is using that same unpack statement to assign the key to `k` and the value to `v`.

Magic! Magic that doesn't work, apparently. I didn't dig deep enough here, and `lambda`s cannot, in fact, unpack values on their own. Instead, do:

```
max_key, max_value = max(d.items(), key = lambda x: len(set(x[1])))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And thanks a lot for the explanation also, I think I'm a bit closer to actually understanding how it works. But, what I don't understand is why it only writes the key, and not the value? How can i make it write both? (I don't really need this, but I think maybe it would make me understand better how it works).

Comment: Wow, thank you! I highly appreciate it, learned a lot :) Again, thanks :D

Comment: Just one last question, I get an error saying that lambda needs to argument. I don't understand why this error comes, when lambda has the arguments k and v?

Comment: you might have to enclose them in parentheses, I didn't actually test this code (heh)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47701/discussion-between-adsmith-and-user2795095)

Comment: @adsmith : btw, you can unpack the values in the lambda using `lambda (k,v)`

Comment: @njzk2 I get a `SyntaxError` on Python 3.3.4, I tried that.

Comment: @njzk2 Apparently it was removed in Python3 as per PEP 3113 http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/

Answer (score 1):

for less advanced user this can be a solution:

```
longest = max(len(item) for item in your_dict.values())
result = [item for item in your_dict.values() if len(item) == longest]
```